# organizar json generado desde mysql en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

estoy obteniendo datos de una base de datos en mysql, aca les dejo mi codigo.

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios";
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM id";  
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
    if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query)) die();    
    $encabezado = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))    {   
        $id = $row["ID_Usuario"];          
        $nombre = $row["Nombre_Usuario"];                  
        $usuario = $row["Usuario"];        
        $pass = $row["Pass"];          
        $empresa = $row["Empresa"];       
        $nit = $row["Nit"];
        $fechareg = $row["FECHA_REG"];
        $n1 = $row["Nota1"];
        $n2 = $row["Nota2"];
        $encabezado[] = array('id'=> $id,'nombre'=>$nombre,'usuario'=>$usuario,'clave'=>$pass,'empresa'=>$empresa,
        'nit'=>$nit,'fecha registro'=>$fechareg,'nota1'=>$n1,'nota2'=>$n2);
        $json_encabezado = json_encode($encabezado,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
    if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query2)) die(); 
    $detalle = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){     
        $codigo = $row["id"];
        $producto = $row["nombre"];
        $valor = $row["valor"];               
        $detalle[] = array('codigo'=>$codigo,'producto'=>$producto,'valor'=>$valor);        
        $json_detalle = json_encode($detalle,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);         
        }   
        echo '<pre>'.$json_encabezado.$json_detalle.'</pre>';
```

?>

este es el resultado de mi codigo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero necesito que $json_detalle salga dentro de $json_encabezado cuando $id sea igual a $codigo

algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien me puede guiar en que debo hacer para obtener los resultados esperados, no soy muy bueno en php pero agradezo su contribucion.

Gracias.

Comment: Para poder ayudarte dime, en los productos cual código se relaciona con el cliente? veo en tu ejemplo 2 "código". ósea como relacionas el producto con los usuarios.

Comment: se relacionan con el campo id y codigo por ejemplo cuando el id del cliente sea 1 y el codigo del producto sea 1 deben salir en el mismo arreglo.

Comment: Me avisas si te sirve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-Primero debes hacer una consulta dentro de tu primer while

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios";

mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query)) die();    
$encabezado = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))    {   
    $id = $row["ID_Usuario"];          
    $nombre = $row["Nombre_Usuario"];                  
    $usuario = $row["Usuario"];        
    $pass = $row["Pass"];          
    $empresa = $row["Empresa"];       
    $nit = $row["Nit"];
    $fechareg = $row["FECHA_REG"];
    $n1 = $row["Nota1"];
    $n2 = $row["Nota2"];
    

    //2- Realizas la consulta dentro para saber que productos tiene
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM id where codigo='".$id."'"; 

      if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query2)) die(); 
        $detalle = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){     
            $codigo = $row["id"];
            $producto = $row["nombre"];
            $valor = $row["valor"];               
            $detalle[] = array('codigo'=>$codigo,'producto'=>$producto,'valor'=>$valor);        
            $json_detalle = json_encode($detalle,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);         
      } 
      $productos=$json_detalle;


    $encabezado[] = array('id'=> $id,'nombre'=>$nombre,'usuario'=>$usuario,'clave'=>$pass,'empresa'=>$empresa,
    'nit'=>$nit,'fecha registro'=>$fechareg,'nota1'=>$n1,'nota2'=>$n2);
    $json_encabezado = json_encode($encabezado,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

Así debería servirte.

Saludos

Comment: si, me agrupo los productos por cliente, pero solamente me sale un grupo, no me muestra los demas.

Comment: Con esa lógica ya puedes armar como desees, ya tienes la idea, de igual manera si no logras nada, avísame y vemos tu código, editas tu pregunta y cargas tu nuevo código

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución es obtener el arreglo `JSON` directamente con una query `sql`, sin necesidad de tener que escribir todo ese código `PHP`.

La siguiente query retorna el arreglo `JSON` con el formato que vos buscás, o sea que no necesitarías procesarlo con `PHP`. No tengo muy clara la estructura de tus tablas, así que es posible que haya que retocar la query.

```
SELECT  JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', ID_Usuario, 'nombre', Nombre_Usuario, 'usuario', Usuario,
                   'clave', Pass, 'empresa', Empresa, 'nit', Nit,
                   'registro', FECHA_REG, 'nota1', Nota1, 'nota2', Nota2, 'productos', sqp.arreglo))
FROM Usuarios u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('codigo', id, 'producto', nombre, 'valor', valor)) AS arreglo
           FROM id
           GROUP BY id) sqp ON u.ID_Usuario = sqp.id;
```